# 'xi' is an undeclared prefix when setting InnerXml of new XmlDocumentFragment

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I'm attempting to add a new node to an existing xml file. The file has the xi namespace defined:

```
<Module xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" ...
```

and contains nodes with:

```
<xi:include href="somefile.xml" />
```

This loads fine, and I can operate on the existing nodes, but if I try to add a new node like so:

```
XmlDocumentFragment frag = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
frag.InnerXml =
    "<SomeNode SomeAttribute=\"\">" +
    "    <xi:include href=\"SomeFile.xml\" />" +
    "</SomeNode>";
```

I get an XmlException for "'xi' is an undeclared prefix"

I presume it is unhappy that the fragment itself does not recognize the namespace, but I'm not seeing any intuitive way to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

As I was writing this question, I had an idea that worked and am posting it in case it helps someone else. I decided to add the offending xml *after* adding the fragment to the document:

```
XmlDocumentFragment frag = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
frag.InnerXml =
    "<SomeNode SomeAttribute=\"\">" +
    "</SomeNode>";

XmlNode newNode = parentNode.AppendChild(frag);
newNode.InnerXml = "<xi:include href=\"SomeFile.xml\" />";
```

If someone has a cleaner way to do this. I am interested to hear what it is.

Answer (score 1):

In `<xi:include href="somefile.xml" />`, `xi` is a namespace prefix.

Namespace prefixes must be declared if used.  You'll have to add on or above the element that uses the namespace prefix, `xi`, its declaration:

```
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
```

If you [temporarily managed to skirt an error message by assembling fragments in a certain manner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43261597/290085), realize that the end result is what matters: if a namespace is used but not declared, you still have a problem.

Comment: The document I'm adding to already has the namespace declaration. It was the fragment that was unhappy, not the document I was intending to add to. This is why adding a "partial" fragment to the document and then adding my (previously) invalid xml, it works fine since the namespace is defined. If there is a better way, I'd like to know

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to post an example in detail here.
The below code is to show how to append a text sinppet to OneNote desktop using C#.
As you may know, the content in OneNote is store as `xml` and has the prefix as `one` for each node.
So the name space `xmlns:one` is set at the first line of the input parts.
`xmlns:one=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote""`

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Append2OneNote;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote;


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.Application onenoteApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.Application();


        string pageId = "{3ACAE6C6-53C5-0C4F-060D-3007A1428E63}{1}{E19561840189956234832620129833010512773022001}";

        onenoteApp.GetPageContent(pageId, out var CurrentPageXml);

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(CurrentPageXml);

        XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        var LastOutline = root.LastChild;
        var LastOEChildren = LastOutline.LastChild;
        var LastOE = LastOEChildren.LastChild;

        var pageContent = "Your text content1";
        string newXML = $@"
                <one:OE alignment=""left"" quickStyleIndex=""1"" selected=""partial"" xmlns:one=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote"">
                <one:T selected=""all""><![CDATA[{pageContent}]]></one:T>
                </one:OE>";

        XmlDocumentFragment xfrag = xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment();
        xfrag.InnerXml = newXML;

 
        LastOEChildren.AppendChild(xfrag);

        onenoteApp.UpdatePageContent(xmlDoc.InnerXml);
    }
}
```